# Why $R_K/aR_K$ has order $a^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be quadratic number field. and $R_K$ be ring of integers of $K$. Then, for all nonzero
$a \in \Bbb{Z}$, why does $R_K/aR_K$ have order $a^2$ ?

I know $R_K$ is a free $ \Bbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$, but the quotient $R_K/aR_K$ is not always isom to $\Bbb{Z}/a\Bbb{Z}× \Bbb{Z}/a\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $L$ is any free abelian group with $n$ generators, then $L/aL$ has order $|a|^n$. Indeed, $L$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $L/aL$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z})^n$ *as an abelian group* and $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ has order $|a|$ (or just $a$ if $a > 0$).

Comment: Let $L=\Bbb{Z}＋i\Bbb{Z}$. $(\Bbb{Z}＋i\Bbb{Z})/(7)$ is isom to $ \Bbb{F}_{49}$ , not isom to your last group. Where am I missing ?

Comment: Forget the ring structure, think only of the abelian group structure. Then it is easy to see that $(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z})/(7)\to (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^2$ by $[a+ib]\mapsto (a,b)$ is a group isomorphism.

Comment: Oh, as a group. ok, you are correct.

Comment: What is $|a|$, did you mean the determinant of the multiplication by $a$ linear map?

Comment: @reuns Should be the absolute value of $a$, no?